# Export results from BigQuery to file using bq query command

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there a way to export the results from BigQuery to a csv file using

**bq query "SELECT name,count FROM mydataset.babynames WHERE gender = 'M' ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 6"** command.

I found that we can give --destination_table=mydataset.happyhalloween parameter which will write to a different table. Is there a similar way to write it to a file?

I also tried **bq query "SELECT name,count FROM mydataset.babynames WHERE gender = 'M' ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 6" > output.txt**

But this creates additional headers
[image]

But I only want results to be written a file

Based on an answer on this thread, I tried the following query,
**bq query --format=csv "SELECT commit FROM [bigquery-public-data:github_repos.commits] LIMIT 10" > output.txt**
It was better but I still got some unnecessary text in the file output.txt

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Useful common flags

Common flags are used between bq and the command. For a full list of flags, call bq --help.

Here are some of the most useful flags:

```
--apilog - Turn on logging of all server requests and responses. If no string is provided (--apilog=), log to stdout; if a string is provided, instead log to that file (--apilog=filename).

--format [none|json|prettyjson|csv|sparse|pretty] - The output format.
```

Comment: Hey when I ran the follwing query,
**bq query --format=csv "SELECT commit FROM [bigquery-publi
c-data:github_repos.commits] LIMIT 10" > output.txt**

I still got some unnecessary text at the top of the file. Can you try it yourself?

Comment: The CSV returnes the header line, eg: the columns for the output. If you got anything else you may try adding the headless and quiet flags: `bq query -q --headless --format=csv "SELECT `

Comment: Hey I tried this command:
bq query --format=csv -q --headless "SELECT commit FROM [bigquery-public-data:github_repos.commits] LIMIT 10" > output.txt


I am still getting "commit" text in the first line of the output file :(

Comment: You will ALWAYS get the HEADER line, commit is the NAME of the column.

Comment: To avoid the header line, use `bq extract --print_header=true `. This extracts a whole table. If you want to select, then you must first `create table $table as select ...`